# Redirecting output for unknown result in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following code that runs through a list of servers which then outputs to a file. Often it comes across a server it can't find the details for and displays the output `Request to dc1.abc.local timed-out`. How do i capture the servers that returned the result in a separate file?

```
FOR /F %%i in (servers.txt) do FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%j in (
  'nslookup %%i ^| find "Name:"'
) do @echo %%j >> dns.txt 2>> output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "timed-out" text is in %%j then test this:

```
FOR /F %%i in (servers.txt) do FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%j in (
  'nslookup %%i ^| find "Name:"'
) do echo %%j |find "timed-out" >> output.txt || echo %%j >> dns.txt
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the timeout message is to stdout or stderr? Does it appear on the Name line?

Comment: @dbenham - Do you mean the message `Request to dc1.abc.local timed-out`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Yes - I don't know the behavior of nslookup. I could envision where more has to change to get the result you want, depending on the answers to those questions in my comment.